# How do I DROP a constraint from a sqlite (3.6.21) table?

Tags: sqlite, constraints, ddl

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE child( 
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  parent_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT parent_id REFERENCES parent(id), 
  description TEXT);
```

How do I drop the constraint?

Comment: http://sqlite.org/lang_dropindex.html

Answer (score 118, accepted):

SQLite does not (as of this answer) support the `alter table drop constraint` command. The allowed syntax can be seen [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). You will need to create a new table without a constraint, transfer the data, then delete the old table.

I think something like the following should work:

```
CREATE TABLE child2 ( 
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    parent_id   INTEGER,
    description TEXT
);
INSERT INTO child2 (id, parent_id, description)
   SELECT id, parent_id, description FROM CHILD;
DROP TABLE child;
ALTER TABLE child2 RENAME TO child;
```

Note that the `insert into` could probably be simplified to *not* use explicit column names but I've left it that way in case you want to change the structure as well.

For example, if you're *removing* the constraint on the `parent_id` column, it's of dubious use to keep it there at all. In that case, you could modify the data transfer to:

```
CREATE TABLE child2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT);
INSERT INTO child2 (id, description) SELECT id, description FROM CHILD;
```

Comment: You can also combine steps 1 & 2 above into one sql statement methinks:  "create table child2 as select * from child;" although you'd have to add the PK constraint manually.

Comment: @chacmool You cannot add a PK constraint manually after the table has been created. [SQLite Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Comment: 2nd statement can be shortened to `INSERT INTO child2 SELECT * FROM CHILD;`

Comment: @Dariush, yes, you could. However, it makes little sense to transfer the parent id if it's not going to be subject to a constraint. I realise I didn't make that entirely clear in my final paragraph so I'll try to clarify it a little.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is an easier, more concise approach:

```
copy db.sqlite3 backup-db.sqlite3
echo .dump tablename | sqlite3 db.sqlite3 > modify.sql
(now delete or change the constraint in modify.sql)
echo drop table tablename; | sqlite3 db.sqlite3 
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 < modify.sql
```

You can now redump the new database table and compare the differences.

Comment: Under Linux/sh, you may need to use `echo drop table tablename\;`.  Notice the backslash before the semicolon.

Comment: Consider also that with paxdiablo's approach, you can put the whole operation inside a transaction which will roll back if any step fails, leaving your db in its original state.  With your approach, you'll want to check for errors at steps 2, 4 and 5 and abort accordingly, which makes the code a lot less concise.

Comment: SQLiteStudio allows you to export the whole database as SQL. Which allows you to proceed much like jftuga does with the command line tool.

Comment: Man, it's is like going to the neighbor house by calling a taxi!

Answer (score 2):

With DB Browser for SQLite you can do this by going to `Modify Table` then clicking on the `constraints` tab, then clicking `Remove constraint`.