# how we can delete foreign-key in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with an SQLite database. I have a table which contain the primary keys of 2 other tables as foreign keys; I want to delete one of them. Here is the code for the table:

```
protected static final String Item_places=(" CREATE TABLE " 
    + Item_place + "(" 
    + place_id + " INTEGER ," 
    + Item_id + " INTEGER  ," 
    + "FOREIGN KEY("+place_id+ ") REFERENCES " + PlaceTable + "("+ PlaceID+ " ) ON DELETE CASCADE" 
    + "FOREIGN KEY("+Item_id+ ") REFERENCES "+ contentTable+ "("+contentID+"));");
```

Answer (score 5):

You would need an `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT` command but [SQLite doesn't support this](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html), see [How do I DROP a constraint from a sqlite (3.6.21) table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884787/how-do-i-drop-a-constraint-from-a-sqlite-3-6-21-table) for a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but it's best to provide an updated answer.

Since API 16 (Aka Android 4.1), it's possible to turn on the FK constraints using `SQLiteDatabase#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean enabled)`.

As [per the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean)):

> Sets whether foreign key constraints are enabled for the database.
>
> **By default, foreign key constraints are not enforced by the database.**
>   This method allows an application to enable foreign key constraints.
>   It must be called each time the database is opened to ensure that
>   foreign key constraints are enabled for the session.

To make this work, inside your custom `SQLiteOpenHelper` use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Enable FK constraints.
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    super.onConfigure(db);
}
```