# Change the primary key of a table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
[id,lang,data]
```

Where the primary key is `id`

I want to change the primary key to  `id,lang` without losing the content of the table. What is the query I must run to change it

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884787/how-do-i-drop-a-constraint-from-a-sqlite-3-6-21-table

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As per the comment by @GarnerJosh, you can't run a single command to change it - SQLite doesn't permit changing existing table structures.  Instead, create a new table with a composite primary key and copy the data over:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_copy( 
    id INTEGER, 
    lang INTEGER,
    data TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, lang)
);
INSERT INTO my_table_copy (id, lang, data)
   SELECT id, lang, data FROM my_table;
DROP TABLE my_table;
ALTER TABLE my_table_copy RENAME TO my_table;
```

Comment: Nice answer, in this case make sure u are not calling onCreate(db) again from your onUpgrade(), If you are doing so then application will again try to create your table and it will cause sqliteException, table already exit. so for avoiding this only drop and create those tables which you want to change. 
Thank you PinnyM and GamerJosh

Comment: There is a detailed information about this method in the Sqlite documentation : https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html "Making Other Kinds Of Table Schema Changes"

Comment: On my testsystem using `INSERT INTO my_table_copy (id, lang, data) SELECT id, lang, data FROM my_table ORDER BY (id,lang);` speeds up the query by factor 2 for larger tables (~100k rows).