# how do i drop constraint with sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, syntax, unique-constraint

I try to drop a constraint if this one exists but i get an error, here is my code and below the error :

```
return knex.schema.raw(
  `
    ALTER TABLE users
    DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "users_customer_id_email_unique",
    DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "users_customer_id_trigram_unique";
  `,
);
```

**My error :**

ALTER TABLE users

```
          DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "users_customer_id_email_unique",
          DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "users_customer_id_trigram_unique";
         - SQLITE_ERROR: near "DROP": syntax errorError: SQLITE_ERROR: near "DROP": syntax error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I DROP a constraint from a sqlite (3.6.21) table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884787/how-do-i-drop-a-constraint-from-a-sqlite-3-6-21-table)

Comment: See the **Making Other Kinds Of Table Schema Changes** section at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html for the needed steps to recreate the table without those constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// we first autorise schema modification
await knex.raw('PRAGMA writable_schema = true');
// then drop unique email_customer_id
await knex
  .select()
  .table('sqlite_master')
  .where('type', '=', 'index')
  .andWhere('tbl_name', '=', 'users')
  .andWhere('name', '=', 'users_email_customer_id_unique')
  .del();

//and also drop unique customer_id_trigram
await knex
  .select()
  .table('sqlite_master')
  .where('type', '=', 'index')
  .andWhere('tbl_name', '=', 'users')
  .andWhere('name', '=', 'users_customer_id_trigram_unique')
  .del();

// I move back the autorisation for schema modification to false
return knex.raw('PRAGMA writable_schema = false');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only **DROP** statements supported by SQLite are :-

- DROP INDEX
- DROP TABLE
- DROP TRIGGER
- DROP VIEW

The **ALTER TABLE** statement is relatively limited as per :-

[image]

**As such you need to recreate the table less the constratints.**

**The following could be the basis for doing that :-**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_users (users_customer_id_email_unique TEXT,users_customer_id_trigram_unique INTEGER, othercolumn);
INSERT INTO new_users SELECT * FROM users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_users;
ALTER TABLE users RENAME TO old_users; /* could be dropped instead of altered but safer to alter then drop */
ALTER TABLE new_users RENAME TO users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_users;
```

## Working Example

Perhaps consider the following example based upon your code. Note that this also includes some extras that could be helpful e.g. extracting the sql with UNIQUE (***all occurences***) removed.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (users_customer_id_email_unique TEXT UNIQUE,users_customer_id_trigram_unique INTEGER UNIQUE, othercolumn);
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('a@email.com',1,'blah'),('b@email.com',2,'blah'),('c@email.com',3,'blah');
/* try to addd some duplicate data (will not be added) */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users VALUES ('a@email.com',1,'blah'),('b@email.com',2,'blah'),('c@email.com',3,'blah');
/*RESULT 1 - data in table before removing unique constraint */
SELECT * FROM users;

/* Potentially useful extras that could be used in generating SQL for new table */
SELECT replace(replace(sql,' UNIQUE',''),' unique','') AS newsql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'users';
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('users');

/* The actual constraint removal using hard coded replacement table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_users (users_customer_id_email_unique TEXT,users_customer_id_trigram_unique INTEGER, othercolumn);
INSERT INTO new_users SELECT * FROM users; /* populate the replacement table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_users; /* just in case */
ALTER TABLE users RENAME TO old_users; /* could DROP the table here instead of ALTER and subsequent DROP */
ALTER TABLE new_users RENAME TO users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_users;
/* Add some duplicate rows */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users VALUES ('a@email.com',1,'blah'),('b@email.com',2,'blah'),('c@email.com',3,'blah');

/* END RESULTS */
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'users' OR tbl_name = 'users';
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('users');

/* Cleanup Testing Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
```

The Results :-

**The data in the original table**

[image]

**Extra** - Replacement SQL example where UNQIUE is removed

[image]

**Extra** - The column info as per the original table

[image]

**The data in the table after it has been altered** (with duplicated data added)
[image]

**SQL for the new table** (also shows that indexes for UNIQUE columns have been dropped)

[image]

**The columns of the replacement table**
[image]