# How to re-parent a table FOREIGN KEY in SQLite after recreating the parent

Tags: sqlite, database-design, database-migration

Consider my vehicle rental company, with two different kinds of rental vehicles:

```sql
CREATE TABLE busses (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    places INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE cars (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    places INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE vehicles (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    bus_id INTEGER,
    car_id INTEGER,

    FOREIGN KEY(bus_id) REFERENCES busses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(car_id) REFERENCES cars(id),

    CHECK (NOT(bus_id IS NULL AND car_id IS NULL))
);

CREATE TABLE rentals(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    vehicle_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY(vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicles(id)
);
```

My vehicle company has done well the past few years. We've ordered a few trucks, and we're planning to rent these out too.  We want to get to this schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE busses (..);
CREATE TABLE cars (..);
CREATE TABLE trucks (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    tar_weight INTEGER NOT NULL,
    max_net_weight INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE vehicles (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    bus_id INTEGER,
    car_id INTEGER,
    truck_id INTEGER,

    FOREIGN KEY(bus_id) REFERENCES busses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(car_id) REFERENCES cars(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(truck_id) REFERENCES trucks(id),

    CHECK (NOT(bus_id IS NULL AND car_id IS NULL AND truck_id IS NULL))
);

CREATE TABLE rentals(...);
```

In mere-mortal SQL, you can move between those two schema's with `ALTER TABLE`.  However, SQLite does not seem to allow rewriting a `CHECK` constraint (e.g. [How do I DROP a constraint from a sqlite (3.6.21) table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1884787/3177936)), nor dropping it and re-adding it.

The solution to this would be to

1. rename the table; then
2. re-create the new table with the new `CHECK` constraint; then
3. re-insert the data from the old table.

Something like

```sql
ALTER TABLE vehicles RENAME TO vehicles_old;
CREATE TABLE vehicles (...);
INSERT INTO vehicles (id, bus_id, car_id) SELECT * FROM vehicles_old;
DROP TABLE vehicles_old;
```

However, renaming the `vehicles` table to `vehicles_old` also renames the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints that come with `busses` and `cars`: they point to the `vehicles_old` table after renaming, as shows by:

```
sqlite> select * from sqlite_schema;
table|busses|busses|2|CREATE TABLE busses (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    places INTEGER NOT NULL
)
table|cars|cars|3|CREATE TABLE cars (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    places INTEGER NOT NULL
)
table|rentals|rentals|5|CREATE TABLE rentals(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    vehicle_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY(vehicle_id) REFERENCES "vehicles_old"(id)
)
table|trucks|trucks|6|CREATE TABLE trucks (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    tar_weight INTEGER NOT NULL,
    max_net_weight INTEGER NOT NULL
)
table|vehicles|vehicles|7|CREATE TABLE vehicles (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    bus_id INTEGER,
    car_id INTEGER,
    truck_id INTEGER,

    FOREIGN KEY(bus_id) REFERENCES busses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(car_id) REFERENCES cars(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(truck_id) REFERENCES trucks(id),

    CHECK (NOT(bus_id IS NULL AND car_id IS NULL AND truck_id IS NULL))
)
```

My question now is: how do I re-parent the `rentals` table, such that it points to the `vehicles` table instead of the non-existing `vehicles_old` table?

Nb., this may be considered an x-y question, where "y" is "reparenting of `rentals`?", and "x" is "how do I update `vehicles`'s check-constraint?". I assume that the latter is not possible.

This should not be considered an x-y-z question where I should introduce a `vehicle_types` and `vehicle_attributes` table; [in my real case](https://gitlab.com/rubdos/whisperfish/-/merge_requests/149) we're really talking ISA-relations.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, 20 minutes after posting, you realise the answer has been staring in you in your eyes for the last hour.

From [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), section "2. ALTER TABLE RENAME":

> Prior to version 3.26.0 (2018-12-01), FOREIGN KEY references to a table that is renamed were only edited if the PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON, or in other words if foreign key constraints were being enforced. With PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF, FOREIGN KEY constraints would not be changed when the table that the foreign key referred to (the "parent table") was renamed. Beginning with version 3.26.0, FOREIGN KEY constraints are always converted when a table is renamed, unless the PRAGMA legacy_alter_table=ON setting is engaged.

While I had tried multiple combinations of both PRAGMA's, I had not realized that `PRAGMA foreign_key=OFF;` [is a no-op during a transaction](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys). Of course, I was running my migration in a transaction with FK checking enabled.  This would not be a problem if we weren't running an ancient SQLite 3.15.2, because there the `PRAGMA legacy_alter_table=ON;` would have been sufficient.

Comment: Not sure whether I should accept my own answer here; while it technically solves the question, it's a bit of an ugly hack (the `legacy_alter_table=ON` is discouraged for new applications). Would be nice to find a better answer to this.