# SQLite - After the constraints on a table were removed, the base grew twice

Tags: sqlite, constraints, size, alter-table

I tried to remove constraints on a huge table as described in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884787/how-do-i-drop-a-constraint-from-a-sqlite-3-6-21-table) - trough creating new table without constraints, copying data from original table, and removing original table. Initial DB size was 80 Gb in size, after "altering" table I have got a DB with size 160 Gb. I tried to "Compact Database" in "DB Browser for SQLite", but nothing was changed. Is there a way to reduce database size?

**Note**. Original DB has many tables, and my huge table has 1) foreign key constraints, and 2) Unique constraint on all foreign keys. New DB have only one huge table with foreign key constraints removed, but unique constraint was not changed. How much can this affect the size?

Comment: Run a `VACUUM`?

Comment: Hm. It did what I needed. But, it took a huge amount of space and time. On a fairly full HDD it brokes, although it worked for more than a day, but on a not too filled SDD in a few hours it made me 80 GB back. Thanks for this tip